# How do I pass a model array into jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array from a model that I would like to use in my jquery script. How do I do that?

```
Model.list
<select id='ddlchanger' onchange="toggleChange(/* pass array here*/)"></select>

function toggleChange(list) {
   for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      $('<option/>').val(list[i]).html(list[i]).appendTo('#drpdownSub');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than binding the on change event in your html, bind it in the javascript, then you can pass in the array.

```
$(function(){
    var Model.list;

    $('#ddlchanger').change(function(){
        toggleChange(Model.list);
    });

    function toggleChange(list) {
        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            $('<option/>').val(list[i]).html(list[i]).appendTo('#drpdownSub');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @user54197: Then you have a different problem. What is your server side language?

Comment: The syntax will depend on your server side language but you can render the list as json and then set your list variable in the javascript side to be that json object. var list = <?php json_encode(Model.list) ?>;

Answer (score 0):

I would attach the event handler with jQuery:

```
var data = [...];

function toggleChange(list) {
   for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      $('<option/>').val(list[i]).html(list[i]).appendTo('#drpdownSub');
   }
}

$(function() {
    $('#ddlchanger').change(function() {
        toggleChange(data);
    });
});
```

which leaves the HTML as

```
<select id='ddlchanger'>
...
</select>
```